# Tomcat stop error

Tags: windows, tomcat

[Event viewer error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FLQq4.png)
tomcat service stop timeout.
I use Tomcat 5.5, JDK1.8.20, the operating system is WinServer2012R2.
I tried to stop the Tomcat service in the window service, but it appeared in the timeout, event viewer error like picture.
Is it related to window update?

Comment: Tomcat 5.5 hasn't been updated since 2012, and it was superseded by Tomcat 6 in 2007! Are you really still using Tomcat 5.5?

Comment: Yes, because this system has been developed for a long time. But Microsoft's operating system has been upgraded and updated, and we don't have time to upgrade our Tomcat version. It used to be normal, but after the completion of the Microsoft operating system update in July, there was a problem that Tomcat stopped overtime, and it was suspected that it was related to the update of the operating system.

Comment: Do you think that the Tomcat version is too old to stop overtime?

Comment: You have not provided enough information to determine the root cause of the problem, and clear resolution is probably not possible anyway, unless the issue is happening regularly. But regardless of that, your statement that _"we don't have time to upgrade our Tomcat version"_ is a concern. You are exposed to all kinds of security risks by running such an old version of Tomcat. Note from Tomcat's web site: [_"Tomcat 5.0.x and 5.5.x are no longer supported. Further vulnerabilities in the 5.0.x and 5.5.x branches will not be fixed."_](http://tomcat.apache.org/security-5.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To skomisa, thank you for your help, I found the answer, and indeed it has a relationship with windows update, you can view this link.
https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/news/microsoft/microsoft-released-windows-7-and-81-cumulative-updates-kb4345459-and-kb4345424/